# Change image rotation in onConfigurationChange

Tags: java, android, imageview, onconfigurationchanged

I want to `rotate image` when `configuration changes`. I found a working code but it **requires Api 17.** How could i make it **compatible for Api 11.**

```
public class CustomImage extends ImageView {

    private Bitmap mSource;

    public CustomImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private CustomImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private CustomImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mSource = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.icony);
    }

    public int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int px = Math.round(dp
                * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
        return px;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        int rotation = getDisplay().getRotation();

        // Checks the orientation of the screen

       /* if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/

        int angle = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            angle = -90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            angle = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            angle = 90;
            break;
        default:
            angle = 0;
            break;
        }

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mSource, 0, 0, mSource.getWidth(),
                mSource.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

}
```

in `onConfigurationChange` i have to handle this image rotation in given methods.

```
 if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
 {
 }
 else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
 {
 }
```

> Or is there any other method which is preferable.

**This statement requires API 17**

```
int rotation = getDisplay().getRotation();
```

Comment: which part requires api level 17 ?

Comment: int rotation = getDisplay().getRotation();   it requires Api 17

Answer (score 1):

`Display.getRotation()` was introduced with api level 8, and probably is `getDispaly()` which requires api level 17. You can use `getSystemService`
 to retrieve the WindowManager and, through it, the default display:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

everything was already there at API level 11's time